# awk Removing some spaces from the end of a column

Tags: awk, gsub

I am trying to remove 2 spaces from the end of the second column of my file using this command:

`awk '{gsub(/[  \$]/, "", $2); print}' Myfile`

The format of my input file looks like this (The characters and numbers here are just for showing the format):

```
   1AA       A      1   9.999   9.999   9.999
 111BB       B   1111   9.999   9.999   9.999
1111AABB  ABCD  11111   9.999   9.999   9.999
```

And I want the output like follows:

```
   1AA       A    1   9.999   9.999   9.999
 111BB       B 1111   9.999   9.999   9.999
1111AABB  ABCD11111   9.999   9.999   9.999
```

In practice, the third column shifts 2 spaces toward the second column.

But my code does nothing :(

Can anyone explain to me what's the problem with my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on you have setup field separator as `|` but your shown samples doesn't have it?

Comment: Sorry for making you confused. I am a beginner and I thought this separator  `|`  means splitting by space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, inside `awk` gsub, `[  \$]` pattern matches one of  two chars: a space or a `$` char and is equal to `[$ ]`.

Since your file is fixed-width, you can use a GNU awk command like

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="10 6 8 8 8 8" } {gsub(/  $/,"",$2); print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6}' Myfile > newMyfile
```

where `/  $/` matches two literal spaces at the end of the input (`$` defines the end of string).

See more about `FIELDWIDTHS` in [*"4.6.1 Processing Fixed-Width Data"* `gawk` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Processing-Fixed_002dWidth-Data).

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,14) substr($0,17)}' file
   1AA       A    1   9.999   9.999   9.999
 111BB       B 1111   9.999   9.999   9.999
1111AABB  ABCD11111   9.999   9.999   9.999
```

or using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS (use `9999` or some other large number instead of `*` if you have an older gawk version that doesn't understand `*` as meaning "the rest of the line"):

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='14 2 *' '{print $1 $3}' file
   1AA       A    1   9.999   9.999   9.999
 111BB       B 1111   9.999   9.999   9.999
1111AABB  ABCD11111   9.999   9.999   9.999
```

The problem with your code is you're trying to remove 2 spaces from $2 but your fields are space-separated so there are no spaces in any field, including $2, the spaces are between fields. Also your regexp `/[  \$]/` means "blank or literal $ char", not "2 blanks before the end of string" as I believe you thought it meant.

Comment: Hello, For me `awk '{print substr($0,1,15) substr($0,17)}'` or `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='15 1 *' '{print $1 $3}'` worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZeusVonVenus your welcome. The different values you used in your comment just mean that your real data is off by a few characters from the sample input you provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `rev` + `awk` + `rev` combination code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
rev Input_file | 
awk '
  match($0,/^\S+(\s+\S+){3}/){
    val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    val2=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    sub(/^  /,"",val2)
    $0=val1 val2
  }
1
' | rev
```

With shown samples, output will be as follows:

```
   1AA       A    1   9.999   9.999   9.999
 111BB       B 1111   9.999   9.999   9.999
1111AABB  ABCD11111   9.999   9.999   9.999
```

***Explanation:*** Following is the detailed level explanation for above code.

```
rev Input_file |                    ##using rev on Input_file to get output in reverse order.
awk '                               ##Sending rev output as standard input to awk.
  match($0,/^\S+(\s+\S+){3}/){      ##using match function of awk to match regex ^\S+(\s+\S+){3}
    val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  ##Creating val1 variable which has matched values in it.
    val2=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  ##Creating val2 variable which has rest of values(after matched value).
    sub(/^  /,"",val2)              ##Substituting starting 2 spaces(which are actually 2 spaces we need to remove between 2nd and 3rd field in question) with NULL in val2 here.
    $0=val1 val2                    ##Assigning val1 and val2 values to current line.
  }
1                                   ##printing current line here.
' | rev                             ##Sending awk program output to rev to print values in actual order.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only problem with the code is that it also shifts the first column (I have a space before the first column, and it should be there). Since my file should have a fix-width, I think I'd better use `FIELDWIDTHS`

Comment: @ZeusVonVenus, thanks for checking the same, if you see I posted output I recived after running my code. It has not removed space from first column. Fieldswidth is good but it has limitation like you have given length as hardcoded ones, this one is not hardcoded one but not sure why it isn't working for you though. I hope you have used 2 times `rev` as shown in my answer 

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what was the problem but I tried your code again, and it worked well this time. Thank you for your help.